# Error exist in paypal PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, paypal

I do not know why this error always appears, but I have already followed all the steps to combine the PayPal Android SDK and the PhoneGap Android PayPal plugin.

e.g.

```
private String environemnt = PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE;
```

and it is the same for

```
PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_NO_NETWORK;PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_LIVE;PaymentActivity.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;
```

and so on.

Comment: Can you please copy and paste the exact error message? The title doesn't look like it's a verbatim error message.